# Code Check for Deletion of last node in circular linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to code to delete the last element in a circular linked list and I dont know if I did something wrong.

I've tried many reference with similar code but mine as shown will not run. Please let me know where I did wrong.

```
def del_end(self):
    if self.head is None:
        print("Cicular Linked List is empty")
    else:
        if self.head == self.tail:
            self.head = None
        else:
            a = self.head
            while a.next != self.tail:
                a = a.next
            self.tail = None
            self.tail = a
            a.next = self.head
```

I've tried typing and running the code many times and it always stop working when I add in the while loop... is there a fix for it?

```
class Node:
def __init__(self,data):
    self.data = data
    self.next = None
class cll:
def __init__(self):
    self.head = None
    self.tail = None
def display(self):
    if self.head is None:
        print("Circular Linked List is empty")
    else:
        a = self.head
        print(a.data,end=" ")
        while a.next != self.head: #go through the list till the end and print node data 
            a=a.next
            print(a.data,end=" ")
        print(a.next.data) #print out 1st node data
def del_end(self):
    if not self.head:
        print("Circular Linked List is empty")
    else:
        if self.head==self.tail:
            self.head=None
        else:
            a=self.head
            while a.next!=self.tail:
                a = a.next
            self.tail = None
            self.tail = a
            a.next = self.head
```

Driver code

```
cl=cll()
n1=Node(10)
cl.head=n1
cl.tail=n1
cl.tail.next=cl.head

n2=Node(2)
cl.tail.next=n2
cl.tail=n2
cl.tail.next=cl.head

n3=Node(33)
cl.tail.next=n3
cl.tail=n3
cl.tail.next=cl.head
cl.display()

cl.del_end()
cl.display()
```

Comment: When `self.head == self.tail` you should also do `self.tail = None`

Comment: Use `elif` for a series of mutually-exclusive conditions, not `if/else` nested inside `else`.

Comment: How should I code it with the elif?

Comment: `if self.head is None: ... elif self.head == self.tail: ... else: ...`

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my while loop? the code seems to stop working after I added while loop in

Comment: The loop looks fine to me.

Comment: Is there anyway I could show you my code and see if there's a problem to cause it to stop working after I add the while  loop?

Comment: Isn't your code already in the question?

Comment: There could be problems with the way you insert into the list, so the loop never ends.

Comment: This is just a portion of it, what do you mean by "the way I insert into the list"? How do I fix it?

Comment: Maybe you're not setting `self.tail` correctly in the insertion methods, so `a.next != self.tail` is always true.

Comment: Please post a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You'd make things easier if you would **only** maintain a reference to the `tail` and not to the `head`. In a circular list that is not empty, the head is **always** the successor of the tail, so there really is no reason to have a separate reference for the head.

Comment: May you write it in code so I can understand your explanation better? Thank you!

Comment: But this has been written hundreds of times before. Please focus on the problem you have encountered. The above comments already address the main issues. Have you implemented the corrections?

Comment: Another remark is that your driver code should  not have to fiddle with assigning to `next` attributes. It should only use the methods of your class to manipulate the linked list.

Comment: The code you have provided produces the expected output. Please edit your question and provide the code that causes the problem, so we can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you're rewriting the value in self.tail, your code should look like this:

```py
def del_end(self):
    if self.head is None:
        print("Circular Linked List is empty")
    else:
        if self.head == self.tail:
            self.head = None
            self.tail = None
        else:
            a= self.head
            while a.next != self.tail:
                a = a.next
            a.next = self.head
            self.tail = a
```

Comment: The problem is that they're *not* rewriting the value in `self.tail`.